# Check if edit is currently displayed in a Delphi VCL TListView

Tags: listview, delphi, vcl, delphi-xe8

When you call `EditCaption` on a TListItem, there is a Edit appearing on it's ListView allowing the user to change the text in the first column of the ListItem.

Is it possible to programmatically check if there's currently such an edit displayed somewhere on a Listview or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine whether the list view is being edited by the [**IsEditing**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.IsEditing) method.